# How to save an empty variable in the condition so that it does not omit a line in the statement but continues next?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement, text

How can I achieve that if the condition stores an 'empty' variable else continues in code? So as not to miss a line

The code goes through the cycle and gradually prints according to the condition

```
if frst==1:
    variable=''
else:
 variable= #code something
```

my output

```
-7 2 0
-8 3 0 

10 11 -12 13 0
```

line spacing is my variable

required output

```
-7 2 0
-8 3 0 
10 11 -12 13 0
```

I need it to be stored in the variable so as not to leave a space. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: `if variable != '': # print something`

Comment: You do not show the code which does the actual printing, and its input. There is no relation between the first block of code and the other two.

Answer (score -1):

use `numpy` `where`

```
import numpy as np
df['variable']=np.where(df.frst==1,'',df['variable'])
```

it will keep `df['variable']` as it is